# The code seems to be ok, but only one part spawns?

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I tried to do a script that spawns parts from replicated storage every second but only one keeps spawning.
here is the script:

```
function PartSpawner1()
    local partToClone = game.ReplicatedStorage.ore
    local newPart = partToClone:Clone()
    newPart.Parent = game.Workspace

    newPart.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-500, 500), math.random(1, 500), math.random(-500, 500))
end

while true do
    PartSpawner1()
    wait (1)
end
```

I tried changing the coordinates and nothing works. The code works fine without position specified.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are the parts that you are spawning anchored? Are they falling off the world and immediately being destroyed? Have you put `print` statements into the `PartSpawner1` function to see that it's only being called once?

Comment: Its being called only once, and I get an error "Position is not a valid member of Tool "Workspace.ore"" I also cant anchor these parts because they are tools and will be not be pickupable.

Comment: Ore isn't a Part, it's a Tool? Try converting it to a Part.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I wanted it to be pickupable by the player, any idea how to spawn tools not parts?

Comment: Okay, so I managed to do that parts spawn and when player clicks on them ore tool is added to players inventory. but how do i modify this scirpt to spawn parts only at a fixed height so player can reach them?